# delete any .svn folders from a root folder to all its subfolders

Tags: linux

I have a folder that has a .SVN solution in it.

I want to go throught the entire directory and its subdirectories, and delete the .svn folder.

I have bash installed, so I can use grep if need.

Answer (score 7):

```
find <path> -type d -name '.svn' -exec rm -rf {} \+
```

Finds all directories of name '.svn' and deletes them recursively.

I'd be really cautious of doing this if you don't own the checkout directory and don't understand why these directories are present. Also note *roe*'s answer about `svn export`.

Comment: that should probably be -name and \; right?

Comment: Yeah, `-nane` was a typo :) The `\+` tells `-exec` to call the command a bit more conservatively by appending arguments.

Comment: sweet! I always used xargs for that, does it also terminate the command, or do I need to add a \; as well if I want more predicates?

Answer (score 6):

in bash:

```
removesvn() {
  cd $1
  for f in */.svn; do
    [ -d "$f" ] && removesvn ${f%/.svn}
  done
  [ -d "$f" ] && rm -rf .svn
}

removesvn .
```

should navigate down through all folders containing an .svn folder and remove it.

HOWEVER, you're probably better off using svn to export (`svn export` I beleive) a vanilla tree without versioning information, which is probably what you're looking for.

**EDIT**
Note that the bash script above only removes .svn folders which are connected to the original one (i.e. it won't remove a/b/c/.svn if b doesn't contain a .svn). If you just want to clear out .svn stuff in your filesystem, find will probably do a better job.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine `find` and `rm` with `xargs` to find and remove all .svn subdirectories from a root directory.

First test the `find` command to check if it finds the right subdirectories,

```
find . -name ".svn"
```

This should display a list of all .svn subdirectories in the current working directory (`.`). Make sure that these are indeed the directories that you want to remove. Then run the following command to actually remove them (note: this cannot be undone),

```
find . -name ".svn" | xargs rm -vrf
```

See `man rm` and `man find` for an explanation of the options.

Answer (score 1):

I used this technique:

> find [path] -name .svn -print0 | xargs -0 rm -R

It worked just fine for me.